# Retrieve company name with GoCardless webhook

Tags: webhooks, gocardless

I'm using GoCardless (sandbox account) webhook for a billing project. I want to recover the clients who choose to pay with GoCardless. The problem is that in the JSON that I get from GoCardless there is no such information.

I need the company name to put the mandate number into a sql database where all my clients are.

**Is there a way to get the company name when a mandate is created ?** Or to connect the mandate number to the company name ?

Here is my code :

```html
<?php
putenv('GC_WEBHOOK_SECRET=my_secret...');
$token = getenv("GC_WEBHOOK_SECRET");
$raw_payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$headers = getallheaders();
$provided_signature = $headers["Webhook-Signature"];
$calculated_signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $raw_payload, $token);
if ($provided_signature == $calculated_signature) {
  $payload = json_decode($raw_payload, true);
    foreach ($payload["events"] as $event) {
      if ($event["resource_type"]=="mandates" && $event["action"]=="created"){
                $mandates=$event["links"];
                $mandate=$mandates["mandate"];
                try
                {
                    $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
                    $bdd = new PDO('sqlsrv...', $pdo_options);
                    $reqi="INSERT INTO goCardLess (client) VALUES ('".$mandate."')";
                    $req = $bdd->query($reqi);
                    $req->closeCursor();
                }
                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
                header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                }
              }
            }
 else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 498 Invalid Token test");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Could you give some example you tried and point out how should look the information you need?

Comment: Yes I edited, hope it's helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GoCardless [webhook events](https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#core-endpoints-events) don't contain any sensitive data - they provide resource IDs so you can retrieve them from the API if needed.

The "mandate created" event contains the mandate ID, and the [API reference for mandates](https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#mandates-get-a-single-mandate) shows that mandate responses contain a customer ID (the customer resource is where you'll find their company name.)

This means you need to [retrieve the mandate](https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/?lang=php#mandates-get-a-single-mandate) through the API, then [retrieve the customer](https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/?lang=php#customers-get-a-single-customer):

```
if ($event["resource_type"]=="mandates" && $event["action"]=="created") {
    $mandate_id = $event["links"]["mandate"];
    $mandate = $client->mandates()->get($mandate_id);

    $customer_id = $mandate->links->customer;
    $customer = $client->customers()->get($customer_id);

    $company_name = $customer->company_name;
}
```

This assumes that you've already [installed and initialised the client library](https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/api/making-your-first-request/?lang=php) as `$client`.